# Akka-streams TCP - consume with different Sinks

Tags: java, akka, akka-stream, akka-tcp

How can I switch Sink connected by `tcp.bind()` to TCP Source? For example, lets say i have:

```
   Sink<ByteString, CompletionStage<Void>> tmpFileSink = FileIO
            .toPath(destination)
            .mapMaterializedValue(this::noticeCompletion);

    tcp
       .bind(host, port)
       .to(Sink.foreach(incomingConnection -> wire(incomingConnection, tmpFileSink)))
       .run(materializer);
```

For now, it saves incoming bytes to `destination` file. I would like to change, the destination file dynamically. How can I achieve that using akka-streams?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `PartitionHub` documentation [here](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-dynamic.html#using-the-partitionhub). This allows you to dynamically switch the elements to different destinations.

In your question you didn't specify how exactly you need to make the decision about where each element should go. If the `PartitionHub` can't cut it you may need to go lower level and implement a custom processing stage. You can see how to do that [here](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-customize.html)